# 64QAM & QPSK calculation

Tags: communication, digital-analog-converter

This is the current situation:

802.11a Wireless network with a maximum datarate of 3/4 64QAM.

Calculate the datarate you get with a 2/3 QPSK.

802.11a uses a bandwidth of 54MHz.

Can anyone help me with this calculation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Shall I post it there?

Comment: Probably. I'm not sure this question can be automatically moved with enough votes (not seeing the DSP site among the options).